# Why $handler is getting different value inside callback?

Tags: php, websocket, rabbitmq

Whenever I print clients of handler inside callback it shows empty even after adding few clients.

I'm naive to php it seems like that every time I'm calling call back function new object of handler is getting passed.

```
{
    <?php

    $handler=new Handler();

    $server = IoServer::factory(
       new HttpServer(
           new WsServer(
            $handler
           )
       ),
       9090   
    );
    $callback = function($msg) {
    echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
    echo $handler->test."\n";
    };
    $pid=pcntl_fork(); 
    if ( $pid == -1 ) {       
        echo "server start fork failed";
        exit(1);
    } else if ( $pid ) {
        $server->run();
    } 


    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest',     'guest');
    $channel = $connection->channel();
    $channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);
    $channel->basic_consume('hello', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);
    while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
       $channel->wait();
    echo count($channel->callbacks);
    }

    ?>
}
```

Below is the handler file

```
{
    <?php
    namespace MyApp;
    use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
    use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
    class Handler implements MessageComponentInterface {

    public $clients;  
    public $test="Test";

    private $handler;
    public function __construct() 
    {    
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        "echo  added";
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) 
    {            
        $this->test="onMessage";

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }
    public function sendAll($msg) 
    {            

        $this->test="sendAll";
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            $client->send($msg);        
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) 
    {     
        $conn->close();
    }
    public function getInstance(){
        if(empty($this->handler))
        {
            $this->handler=new Handler();
        }
        return $this->handler;
    }

    } 

    ?>
}
```

Comment: `$handler` is going to be out of scope in your callback.... `$callback = function($msg) use($handler) {
echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
echo $handler->test."\n";
};` perhaps

Comment: I have tried your approach but not working, I also tried to use $GLOBAL for saving handler & using it in call back.
It's looks like that when we pass object to WsServer its getting cloned, now we have 2 copies of handler, that's why we are getting the same vale for "test" variable, to eliminate this bug I have also tried to pass references to WsServer, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the singleton.

Not this:

```
// class Handler... 
private $handler;
...
public function getInstance(){
    if(empty($this->handler))
    {
        $this->handler=new Handler();
    }
    return $this->handler;
}
```

`$handler=new Handler();`

But this:

```
// Changed class Handler... 
private static $handler;
...
public static function getInstance(){
    if(empty(self::$handler))
    {
        self::$handler=new Handler();
    }
    return self::$handler;
}
```

`$handler=Handler::getInstance();`

[edit] Handler::getInstance() isn't currently static, caught that after I wrote my answer.